# Can't change sound volume anymore since upgrading from Linux Mint (Kernel 5.4) to Linux Mint 21.1 (Kernel 5.15) using an external sound card

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio, audio-volume

I've upgraded from Linux Mint 19.3 with kernel 5.4 to Linux Mint 21.1 with kernel 5.15.

Now I cannot change the sound volume (using the sound icon in the task bar) of my speakers which are connected via my external USB sound card/DAC "Behringer UCA222" anymore. This sound card is over 10 years old and known to work very well with Linux.

**So the problem is, that while I can hear sound and I can also mute it, I cannot change the volume of it.**

What I've tried:

- Installing pavucontrol and tried all possible profiles and played
  around with every knob but no success
- Installing Kernel 5.19, with no success.